# To make fiaunce to someone

Tags: meaning, archaicisms, middle-english

From *Le Morte d'Arthur*:

> *(modern edition)*
>   And when Sir Ector was come he **made fiaunce to the king** for to nourish
>   the child like as the king desired;
>
> *(original edition)*
>   And whan syre Ector was come / he **made fyaūce to the kyng** for to
>   nourisshe the child lyke as the Kynge desyred

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiaunce), *fiaunce* means *confidence*, *fealty*.

Does it mean Sir Ector swore to the king that he would nourish the child?

Comment: (from http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED15868)

maken fiaunce, (a) to make a pledge or a promise, give solemn assurance;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As olegst observes in a comment above, maken fiaunce has the meaning "to make a pledge or a promise, give solemn assurance." A more detailed version of the entry that olegst cites appears in Hans Kurath, [*Middle English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=m6W1r0q2790C&pg=PA542&dq=%22fiaunce%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ77zs3rjTAhVK8WMKHaxeCiUQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22fiaunce%22&f=false) (University of Michigan Press: 1998):

> **fiaunce** n. Also **fience**; cp. **affiaunce**. **1. (a)** Trust or faith (in someone or something); (b) confidence based on trust; assurance. [Examples omitted.] **2.** **maken fiaunce**, **(a)** to make a pledge or a promise, give solemn assurance; **(b)** *mil.* to put oneself on parole. (a) (al470) Malory *W[or]ks* 11/8: He made fyaunce to the kyng for to nourisshe the child. c1475 *Regina celi gwene* 27: The Rede appul of my gardyne, For mannes soule hath made fyaunce. ...

Nathan Bailey, [*An Universal Etymological English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=q05GAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP340&dq=%22fiaunce%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT8a-h2LjTAhUEwWMKHdg2D_sQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22fiaunce%22&f=false) (1773) has this entry for *fiaunce*:

> FIAUNCE, Affiance. *Chauc[er]*.

and these entries for *affiance* (two as a as a verb and one as a verb):

> AFFIANCE {*Affiance*, F.} Confidence, Hope, Trust.
>
> AFFIANCE {in *Law*} the Plighting of Troth between a Man and a Woman upon Agreement of Marriage.
>
> To AFFIANCE {*affidare*, L.} to betroth.

*Troth* is, in essence, fidelity to a promise, so it follows that to *make fiaunce* is, broadly, to promise to make good on an action or obligation that one has been charged with performing or upholding.